Read version from local properties file and set in libs.versions.toml file in Android
I'm using the libs.versions.toml file in Android for version catalogs as described here. I have a properties file in my project which contains the version for a library which I'm using as a dependency. This properties file gets updated periodically with the latest version number and hence I need to read the version number from it. How can I read it from within the libs.versions.toml file and assign it inside the [versions] section of the file?
As an alternative, I am able to declare a custom catalog inside the settings.gradle.kts file as mentioned here and use the Java File class to read the properties file and extract the version number and use it as the version  like below and build successfully.
settings.gradle.kts
val rootProjectDir = rootProject.projectDir
val propFile = File("$rootProjectDir/local_properties_file")
val props = Properties()
propFile.inputStream().let {
        stream -> props.load(stream)
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("testLibs") {
            version("test", props.getProperty("test_version"))
            library("test", "com.test.test", "test-test").versionRef("test")
        }
    }
}

build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation(testLibs.test)
}

However, Android Studio throws a warning stating that it does not support Version Catalog entries in settings.gradle and that they should be defined inside the libs.versions.toml file.

Is there a way to do this in the libs.versions.toml file?

Have you considered having the libs.versions.toml file be the source of truth for your version information like it is meant to be?
